# Magento2.3 SetTemplate is not working first time ajax

Tags: adminhtml, sales-order, custom, magento2.3.0, create-order

I would like to add additional some field info in `sales_order_create_index.xml` 
I used setTemplate:

```
<referenceBlock name="data">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Custom::order/create/data.phtml</argument>
        </action>

    </referenceBlock>
```

If I create order from sales > order > create order > select customer > go to create order page. It still get template in core magento.

Once I reload that page or reorder, it load correct my template.
Anyone know that problem